# Error: Output argument "Clus_Area" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to

Tags: matlab, function

Have 2 matrices, dimensions 1440 rows by 241 columns. First matrix populates each cell with its area, and the second contains values from 0 to 871. These cells are grouped, and values 1 to 871 represent different groups, ie group 1 comprised of 10 neighboring cells, group 2 comprised of 20 neighboring cells, etc.

I want to build a third matrix, 871 rows by 1 column, that lists the area of each group of cells from the second matrix, with the areas calculated by summing the relevant cells from the first matrix.

I tried running a function, but keep getting this error:

```
clear all 
clear
load Clusters_28Aug.mat;  
AR = A>0; 
U = Cluster_Area(AR)
```

> Error in Cluster_Area (line 13) i = 1;
>   Output argument "Clus_Area" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to.

I thought the variable was assigned within the function. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
function Clus_Area = Cluster_Area(AR)
% Summer 2013 Project
%
% Purpose:  To determine the area of each cluster, by adding up the individual areas of each cell within a cluster.
%  Input
%  AR(i,j) = clusters ID'd, on a 1440 x 241 matrix
%
% Output
% Clus_Area(i,j) = area of each cluster, single column vector, indexed by cluster #

i = 1;
j = 1;

for i = 1:1440;  %For all longitudes        
    for j = 1:120;  %For 30S to Equator, convert 0.25 deg lon to km, varies by latitude         
        if AR > 0;              
            b_1 = (111.41288*cosd(abs((0.25*(j+239))-90)))-(0.0935*cosd(abs(3*((0.25*(j+239))-90))))+(0.00012*cosd(abs(5*((0.25*(j+239))-90))));
            b_2 = (111.41288*cosd(abs((0.25*(j+240))-90)))-(0.0935*cosd(abs(3*((0.25*(j+240))-90))))+(0.00012*cosd(abs(5*((0.25*(j+240))-90))));

            %Use area formula for trapezoid A = 1/2 h (b_1+b_2), where h = 27.8km
            Area_cell = (((0.5)*27.8*1000)*((b_1+b_2)*1000));  %Ans converted to m^2

            %Add up cell areas to get cluster area
            Clus_Area(i,j) = sum(Area_cell);
            disp('Clus_Area')
            %Populate Grid_LAT_LON with area of each cell
            %Grid_LAT_LON(i,j) = Area_cell;         
        end      
    end     

    for j = 121:241;  %For Equator to 30N, convert 0.25 deg lon to km, varies by latitude
        if AR > 0;          
            b_1 = (111.41288*cosd(((0.25*(j+239))-90)))-(0.0935*cosd((3*((0.25*(j+239))-90))))+(0.00012*cosd((5*((0.25*(j+239))-90))));
            b_2 = (111.41288*cosd(((0.25*(j+240))-90)))-(0.0935*cosd((3*((0.25*(j+240))-90))))+(0.00012*cosd((5*((0.25*(j+240))-90))));

            %Use area formula for trapezoid A = 1/2 h (b_1+b_2), where h = 27.8km
            Area_cell = (((0.5)*27.8*1000)*((b_1+b_2)*1000));  %Ans converted to m^2            
            %Add up cell areas to get cluster area
            Clus_Area(i,j) = sum(Area_cell);
            disp('Clus_Area')
            %Populate Grid_LAT_LON with area of each cell
            %Grid_LAT_LON(i,j) = Area_cell;         
        end                       
    end     
end
Z = Clus_Area(i,j);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to say

```
if AR(i,j)>0
```

I'm not sure what the semantics of an if statement when the expression results in an array, but I think it might require all elements of the expression to be true.